# Lock mode to Utility in NEI config?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I'm running a Minecraft FTB (TPPI) server for me and some friends, and I want to lock NEI to utility mode. I found the config option:

```
#For those who can't help themselves.
#Set this to a mode and you will be unable to change it ingame
lockmode=-1
profileRecipes=false
utilities=delete, magnet
```

but I can't find any info on what to set lockmode too. I would also be able to deop everyone if I did this, so they wouldn't have to be opped to use utility mode.

Comment: Why do you have everyone opped in the first place? There might be a better solution to the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: deop them, cheat mode is available for ops by default

Comment: @Jochem For utility mode.

Comment: @ratchet I know that, and I did when I popped them.

Comment: @Aiden: Yes, obviously, but why do they need utility mode? Killing rain and the magnet are both replicated by several mods, some of which I'm sure are in TPPI as well. Off the top of my head for rain: forestry, xeno's reliquary, and I think Random Things. The magnet is replicated in Magic bees, xeno's, and modular powersuits.

Comment: @Jochem We may use those later, but magic and trash are useful for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in terms of wanting to De-op people but still have them able to use utilities in my config files there is a config file called **NEIserver** where you can set utilities such as **HEAL** to be allowed by "**ALL**" or "**OP**" or "**NONE**". For example i set HEAL = ALL so that everyone can use the heal utility

Hope this helps

Comment: Didn't even see that! I'll try it this weekend as well!

Answer (score 2):

As you have said your config file looks like this:

```
#For those who can't help themselves.
#Set this to a mode and you will be unable to change it ingame
lockmode=-1
profileRecipes=false
utilities=delete, magnet
```

You need to change it to this:

```
#For those who can't help themselves.
#Set this to a mode and you will be unable to change it ingame
lockmode=1
profileRecipes=false
utilities=delete, magnet
```

lockmode can be set to

```
1. lockmode=-1     #this is unlocked (can change the mode in game).
2. lockmode=0      #Recipe just the recipes no spawning in items.
3. lockmode=1      #Utility the one that you wanted.
4. lockmode=2      #Cheat locks the game on cheat mode.
```

Comment: Does this effect people connecting to the server?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think it does. Make sure it is your servers config file.

Comment: As far as I've been able to test, it doesn't force the client to do anything. In fact, de-opped players are incapable of changing to utility or cheat mode regardless of server settings.