# Where do I find the NEI configuration file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

In Nei how do I find the configuration file? I am trying to lock it to a mode where it only shows me the recipes and I can't cheat in anything even if I wanted to. But I can't find the configuration file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock mode to Utility in NEI config?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160746/lock-mode-to-utility-in-nei-config)

Comment: @Caleb This is not a duplicate of that, this is about the physical location on the disk, not "how do I change something in the file?"

Comment: @Arperum Thanks for pointing that out, I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: andy has two posts about oposite things, in this one he can't get in cheat mode in the other he is stuck in cheat mode somethiing doesnt seem right http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177035/nei-need-help-it-keeps-cheating-in-blocks

Answer (score 1):

For the mod NEI (NeverEnoughItems), your configuration file can be found here:
**%AppData%/Roaming/.minecraft/config/NEI.cfg**
or more familiarily: **C:/Users/*[Your username]*/Roaming/.minecraft/config/NEI.cfg**

---

As for adding a lock on cheatmode, simply change this line in the configuration file:

```
    cheatmode=0
```

*Line 22* - Deactivate Cheatmode

```
    lockmode=1
```

*Line 29* - Activating Lockmode

**Note: Line numbers may vary from version to version.**

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that if this is a mod pack then the settings will be in user mode but the main setting are set in global,

Open the NEI setting by pressing E then click options in the bottom left then click inventory.

in the top right there will be a button you need to make sure this says global before making any changes to the settings so that they apply to the game as a whole.

Hope this helps. this is the case with most mod packs.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He asked where the config file was located.

Comment: The question is specific to the config file, not for the ingame location of the settings

Comment: I'm guessing that he doesnt know about the setting. all options in the config other than lock mode are in options.

Comment: this is also his second post he just wants to know how to change between the two modes

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to know how to get into lock mode. Quote: `I am trying to get it to be in a mode where it only shows me the recipes and I can't cheat in anything even if I wanted to`

Comment: in nei if you are in recipe mode you can't cheat anything in, you don't have to put it into lock mode

Comment: But you can lose some will and change it ingame. If you have it locked, that's impossible.

Comment: The OP want's to change it so if he is tempted to change back into cheat mode he can't (other than editing the config file again).

Comment: he didn't ask how to make it so it couldnt be turned back permenantly

Comment: But he *did* ask how to do it through the configfile and not through the ingame option. Because locking to a mode is also impossible through ingame options.

Comment: Arperum and Caleb are right I was looking for the configuration file I already new of the options menu.